# Mongo search in nested array

Tags: mongodb

How to find documents with one of `cat_id` value (for example for `cat_id=3`)?

Here is sample of collection data:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("51818aabfa746a8e3e000000"),
  "category_set": {
    "cat_id": [
      3,
      7,
      53,
      22,
      24
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated (Shell script or JavaScript preferred).

Comment: `db.databank.findOne({'category_set.cat_id':3})` to find all who have a `cat_id` with a element of `3` in

Comment: OMG.... I try without quotes... I need more coffee. Thank you
db.databank.findOne({category_set.cat_id:3})
Wed May 22 22:23:53.611 JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Answer (score 0):

You do this with the simple query:

```
db.databank.findOne( { 'category_set.cat_id' : 3 } );
```